# The [resources] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

**This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the [answer below](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/a/622/800). If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.**

---

The [resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) tag currently has this tag wiki excerpt:

> Materials used to aid in the process of language learning, whether they be in print, online, or in person.

This seems fine until you realize that we have a [physical-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-resources) tag and an [electronic-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-resources) tag, which completely cover the scope of the [resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) tag.

The [physical-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-resources) tag's wiki excerpt is:

> Physical resources such as dictionaries, text books, audio recordings, flash cards, etc, as opposed to online or electronic resources.

The [electronic-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-resources) tag's wiki excerpt is:

> Language learning materials that are primarily hosted online or in an sort of electronic medium; examples include audiobooks, movies, and songs.

**Can we delete the [resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) tag?**

Comment: All questions with the [tag:resources] tag have been retagged and the description now has a warning and advises users to use the other tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) is too broad especially given two tags that are much more narrow in scope that also deal with resources all together.

With [physical-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-resources) and [electronic-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-resources) in play, this tag is now obsolete. If one has a narrow question, the OP should be able to narrow down to one of those tags. So, let's use our resources (sorry for the pun) to **burninate [resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources)**. If necessary, the OP could use both.

These are two examples questions that could be tagged with [electronic-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-resources) but are currently tagged with [resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources):

- [Through which language can you learn the most other languages online?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/496/through-which-language-can-you-learn-the-most-other-languages-online)
- [Are there any free online resources for learning Tamazight?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/are-there-any-free-online-resources-for-learning-tamazight)

Comment: " If necessary, the OP could use both." - if we go down that path, it may be worth incorporating that into the tag wiki.

Answer (score 3):

There are cases when learners will be looking for *any* resources, regardless whether they are physical or electronic. If we keep the tag [resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources), this single tag will then be sufficient, instead of tagging the question with both [physical-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-resources) and [electronic-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-resources). So this would be an argument to keep the tag [resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources).

Comment: In that case, they should use both tags.

Comment: @fi12 That needs to be added to Anthony Pham's response.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe I already have in the last sentence of the second paragraph: "If necessary, the OP could use both."

Answer (score 1):

All questions with the [resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resources) tag have been retagged to use [physical-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-resources), [electronic-resources](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronic-resources) or both. In addition, the tag wiki excerpts now reads as follows:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG. Instead, use [physical-resources], [electronic-resources] or, if necessary, both.
>
> (Old description: Materials used to aid in the process of language learning, whether they be in print, online, or in person.)

There a several options to progress with it:

- [burninating the tag)([What does it mean to "burninate" a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120640/340816)): strictly speaking, since the tag is not used by any questions, we should not need to do anything (accept retagging questions now and then).
- [blacklisting the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295148/340816): this makes sure that the tag can never be re-created again. This requires that we put a [tag-blacklist-request](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-blacklist-request) question on our meta site, since only Stack Exchange employees can blacklist a tag.

Note: [Why do we burninate instead of blacklisting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242624/340816) points out that

> blacklisting was not designed as an integral part of the tag system. It's an add-on, intended for rare problems that cannot be handled any other way.

For this reason, I would suggest that we don't create a blacklist request, unless we get serious problems in the future.